# CSV file with labels stops at line 1 in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file intended to be loaded into LibreCalc, and it look like this:

```
Volts,Inverter
23.02,0
23.20,0
```

etc.

As long as I go in with VI and remove that first line it plots just fine.

But when I just feed the file in directly, the plot command fails with

```
Bad data on line 1 of file xxxxx
```

If there a way to make it skip malformed error lines and just keep going?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either skip that first line (gnuplot version 5) with

```
plot "file" using 1:2 skip 1
```

or even use that first row to label your plot

```
plot "file" using 1:2 title columnheader
```

Comment: Upvote and accept - Excellent. Thank you so much. That is precisely what I wanted to know.